# Do while loop to restart program if user chooses yes not behaving correctly

Tags: c++

Hi im studying c++ and we havent covered loops yet in C++, but i feel the need to step into new territory, so i made a program from scratch that kindof resembles a grocery store, at the end of the program, it asks if the user wants to shop more, if he/she types Y then it restarts, if he/she types N then it exits.  When i get to the end of the program and type Y, it keeps asking "Do you want to continue shopping? Yes[Y] or No[N]".  Whats up with that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char shoppingMenu()
{
    char chrSelect = ' ';

    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "% Shopping %" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Prepared Foods:" << endl;
    cout << "A.) Lettuce" << endl;
    cout << "B.) Noodles" << endl;
    cout << "C.) Bottled Water" << endl;
    //shopSelection = cin.get();
    cin >> chrSelect;
    return toupper(chrSelect);
}
double lettuce(int numWeight, double numQuant)
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "% Lettuce %" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "Lbs: ";
    cin >> numWeight;
    cout << endl << "Quantity: ";
    cin >> numQuant;
    return numQuant * (numWeight * .75);
}
double noodles(double numQuant)
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "% Noodles %" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "Number of 1/2lb packs: ";
    cin >> numQuant;
    return numQuant * 1.50;
}
double water(char chrSelection, int numQuant)
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
    cout << "% Water %" << endl;
    cout << "%%%%%%%%%" << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "A.) 12pk;";
    cout << endl << "B.) 24pk;" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter [A] or [B]" << endl;
    cin >> chrSelection;
    //cout << '\b' << endl;
    chrSelection = toupper(chrSelection);
    cout << "Quantity: ";
    cin >> numQuant;
    if (chrSelection == 'A')
    {
        return numQuant * 1.49;
    }
    else if (chrSelection == 'B')
    {
        return numQuant * 2.49;
    }
}
int main()
{

    char selection = ' ';
    int numberLettuce = 0;
    double lettuceWeight = 0.0;
    int lettuceQuant = 0;
    double lettuceTotal = 0.0;
    int noodleQuant = 0;
    double noodleTotal = 0.0;
    char waterSelection = ' ';
    int waterQuant = 0;
    double waterTotal = 0.0;
    char keepShopping = ' ';

    cout << "#################" << endl;
    cout << "# Grocery Store #" << endl;
    cout << "#################" << endl << endl;
    do {
        cout << "How may i help you?" << endl;
        cout << "A.) Shopping Program" << endl;
        selection = cin.get();
        selection = toupper(selection);
        system("CLS");

        if (selection == 'A')
        {
            char shopSelection = shoppingMenu(); // Display Menu
            cout << "(Selection == " << selection << ")" << endl;

            if (shopSelection == 'A')
            {
                lettuceTotal = lettuce(lettuceWeight, lettuceQuant);
            }
            else if (shopSelection == 'B')
            {
                noodleTotal = noodles(noodleQuant);
            }
            else if (shopSelection == 'C')
            {
                waterTotal = water(waterSelection, waterQuant);
            }
            system("CLS");
            cout.precision(2);
            cout << fixed;
            cout << "   Lettuce total: $" << lettuceTotal << endl;
            cout << "   Noodle total: $" << noodleTotal << endl;
            cout << " + Water total: $" << waterTotal << endl;
            cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
            cout << " = $" << (lettuceTotal + noodleTotal + waterTotal);
        }
        cout << endl << endl << "Do you want to continue shopping? Yes[Y] or No[N]" << endl;
        cin >> keepShopping;
        keepShopping = toupper(keepShopping);
        system("CLS");
    }
    while (keepShopping == 'Y');
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is

```
cin >> keepShopping;
```

where `keepShopping` is a `char`. When you type <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, you have typed *two* characters. The first one goes into `keepShopping` and your program correctly loops back around to the top of the `do` loop. Then the `selection = cin.get()` reads the next character in the input buffer, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, which is not `A`, so it drops to the end of your `if` block and asks whether you want to continue shopping again.

The solution is to avoid the use of `cin`, and use `getline()` instead.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
keepShopping = str[0];
```

This will consume everything you type including the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress, and you won't get these weird input buffering effects. Using `cin >>` for interactive input is really quite troublesome and you'll save yourself a lot of headache if you avoid it.

Comment: is there method like getline that gets chars instead?  keepShopping is a char.

Comment: No, just get a line of input and look at the first character of the line (`str[0]` as above).

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks for the prompt answers!

Answer (score 1):

What Greg said is correct but you can also use `getch();` but then you need to include c-headers, getch(); will read only 1 key stroke on the keyboard, so if you click "y" it will automatically recognize it without need for pressing enter.

```
keepShopping = getch();
```

I'm not sure in which library it's located but standard c-libraries like `<stdio.h>` are included in form of `#include <cstdio>` and then you can use all standard c functions so just try them out if you pick this solution.

Comment: To be honest I didn't really understand what you just said but it looked like you're referring to getchar(), or maybe I'm wrong but yes getch() will read enter if you click it.

Comment: Oh, sorry I was confused between `getch` and `getchar`. Looks like `getch` is part of curses, which is a whole different topic.

Comment: Correct, getchar() unlike getch() requires an enter at the end of input therefore is used for reading char arrays while getch() reads only a single keystroke at the time.